# is it possible to install a software for all python3 versions existing in the system

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I have python 3.5 and python3.6 both installed on ubuntu 16.04. I switch between them using the command `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` and now I have python 3.6 as the default python3.
I want to build opencv from source, and I want it to be installed on all python3 versions (and on python2 as well). I know that it will be installed for python 2.7 and python 3.6, but how to install it for python3.5 too, at the same time?

Comment: `for VERSION in 2.7 3.5 3.6; do pip$VERSION install <package>; done`

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta actually I want to build opencv from source, what do I do?

Comment: Just repeat the installation for all 3 versions. Note that a certain package may not be compatible with all 3 versions. so you **may** have to rebuild the package for each version in order to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Learn `virtualenv` and `pipenv`.

Environvment creation is **basic** skill for modern python.

I suggest `pipenv`:

```
pip install pipenv
mkdir py35 && cd py35
pipenv install --python 3.5
```

Enjoy!